# Where can I find the Mimic Chest boss?

Tags: lost-ruins

I came across a video of a Mimic Chest boss fight in Lost Ruins. I've already beaten the final boss but I never came across the Mimic fight in my playthrough. How do I access the Mimic Chest boss fight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's a side area to the right of the Catacombs Entrance warp area. It's a separate path that loops back, ending in the boss fight and an openable gate that leads back to the entrance.

[image: Screenshot of the area]

This was taken at the appropriate warp zone, with a flag added to the side area.

Incidentally, the mimic boss is not really a chest, and therefore will not affect the Ascetic Lifestyle quest.